# ProcessTabKey(true) not working on c# splitcontainer at keydown event of windows form

Tags: c#, .net

i am trying to use `ProcessTabKey()` method not working on c# splitcontainer at keydown event of windows form

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BringToFront();
        this.Focus();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {

                e.Handled = true;
                this.ProcessTabKey(true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Thanks for quick response Chibueze Opata. i want that if i press enter then focus to next control in splitcontainer. processTabkey is not working on controls that are in split container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. Ensure that all the controls you want to select have their `TabStop` property set to true.

Comment: splitcontanier tabstop property is already true. ProcessTabKey() is working fine on Tab key but not working on enter key.

Answer (score 0):

Use SendKeys.send("{tab}"); instead of  this.ProcessTabKey(true);